# How to write an android service to run indefinitely and take advantage of location services

Tags: android, android-service

I am new to android services and have followed some tutorials online notably Vogalla's tutorials. My app is designed to stop working when the user is moving at speed > 10 kmph. but to get it working again the user must be stationary for more than 180 seconds. To detect this situation it becomes imperative to keep a background service running to keep track of the time. Below is my code -

```
package com.opaxlabs.text;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private LocationManager manager;
    private String provider;
    private Location location;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private float speed;
    private boolean stationary=false;
    private Handler h;
    private long lastFix=System.currentTimeMillis();

    public MyService() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("My Service command started", "My Service command started");
//      return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!enabled) {
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
        }
        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = manager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 180, 0, this);
        h=new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                long current=System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(current-lastFix>180000){
                    stationary=true;
                    standing();
                }
                h.postDelayed(this, 1800);
            }
        }, 1800);
//      lastFix=System.currentTimeMillis();

        Log.i("My Service created", "My Service created");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        speed = location.getSpeed();
        if(speed>10.0){
            travelling();
            lastFix=System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        stationary=false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public boolean isStationary(){
        return stationary;
    }

    private void travelling(){
        Intent intent=new Intent("Travelling");
        sendMotionBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void standing(){
        Intent intent=new Intent("Standing");
        sendStationaryBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void sendStationaryBroadcast(Intent intent){
        intent.putExtra("stationary", isStationary());
        intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
        intent.putExtra("lng", lng);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void sendMotionBroadcast(Intent intent){
        intent.putExtra("speed", speed);
        intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
        intent.putExtra("lng", lng);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.i("My Service started", "My Service started");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("My Service stopped", "My Service stopped");
        super.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

But I notice a problem here. onCreate() seems to be called each time my app is run. That way I lose the previously saved lastFix and can't reliably determine if the user was stationary for more than 180 seconds. Is the service being recreated each time the app is run? What am I doing wrong here?
Please help me with your suggestions. Thanks in advance.
Edit:
I have performed a few more tests on the app and found that onCreate() was being called each time but not onDestroy() so probably the service is not being recreated but onCreate() being called causes the variables to be reset. Thanks again.

Comment: service are stopped as android needs resources. so it get recreated.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/blackcj/20efe2ac885c7297a676

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid your service from recreate then you can try this hack

step 1 create one static boolean variable in MyService service globally

step 2 `onStartCommand` check if that is true/false and there you can take decission

Answer (score 0):

You can save the lastFix variable by using SharedPreferences, then on "onCreate" load and use it.